# Task.Run and Func<>

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

How can I run a Task that return value and takes a parameter? I see that there is an overloaded method `Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)` but how I can pass a parameter there?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Func<TResult>` doesn't take a parameter. Typically you would *capture* the parameter using a lambda expression instead. For example:

```
public void DoSomething(string text)
{
    Task<int> task = Task.Run(() => text.Length);
    ...
}
```

Here `text` is a *captured variable*... so even though you're just creating a `Func<int>`, it's *using* the method parameter.

Comment: @BVernon: Assuming you don't change the value of `text` later on, it looks fine to me.

Comment: I think I'm just forgetting some really basic stuff... if I call DoSomething multiple times with different values for text then there will be a copy of each version in memory for each call, right?

Comment: i.e. the lambda couldn't possibly use the value of text that was sent in on a different call to DoSomething?

Comment: @BVernon: There'll be a different instance of a compiler-generated class created for each call. So no, the calls won't see each others `text` values.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the Task.Factory.StartNew() overloads to pass in a "state" object that holds all the parameters you want to you use.  Here's a very basic example passing in a NameValueCollection, but you could obviously pass in any type of object you wanted.

```
Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(
    ( a ) => {
        NameValueCollection nvc = a as NameValueCollection;
        if( nvc != null ) {
            nvc.AllKeys.ForEach( k => Console.WriteLine( nvc[k] ) );
        }
        return true;
    },
    new NameValueCollection() { { "param1", "hithere!" } } );
```